# List as Function Arguments in Python

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

If I were trying to input a list as an argument to a function in Python, is there any way to retain the argument as a list or will it have to be passed in one element at a time?

Comment: Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you add some examples ?

Comment: By default the argument will still be a list and not a series of variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass the list as is, then it will stay as a list.

```
>>> def myfunc(*args):
        for arg in args:
            print(arg)
>>> sample_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> myfunc(sample_list)
[1, 2, 3]
```

The function prints the list as one item.

However, if you use the 'splat' or 'unpack' operator `*`, the list can be passed as multiple arguments.

```
>>> myfunc(*sample_list)
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are looking for is this:

```
my_list = ["arg1", "arg2", None, 4, "arg5"]
print(*my_list)
```

is equivalent to:

```
print("arg1", "arg2", None, 4, "arg5")
```

Comment: I think this is the oposite of what the OP wants

Comment: @Metareven what makes you think so?

Comment: Because he says he wants to retain the argument as a list and not pass it as individual arguments. You on the other hand are explaining how to unpack a list of variables which means that you send each element of the list as an argument to the function, instead of retaining it as a list

Comment: @Metareven by saying each element he probably means `print(args[0], args[1], args[2])` and not what really happens. Anyways, let OP decide.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but it's hard to make code in comments/

Probably you meant this:

```
def f(a, b):
    print("f(%s, %s)" % (a, b))

l = [1, 2]
f(*l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the object inside the function that you pass as argument. If your argument is a list, then you get a list inside the function, of course as one proper list and not as single variables.

```py
def func1(my_list):
    print(type(my_list), my_list)

func1([1, 2, "abc"])

# output: <type 'list'> [1, 2, "abc"]
```

However, you can use several ways to achieve something else. You can...

1. Pass single arguments when calling the function, but receive all of them as single tuple (immutable list).

   ```py
   def func2(*my_list):  # the * means that this parameter collects 
                         # all remaining positional arguments
       print(type(my_list), my_list)

   func2(1, 2, "abc")

   # output: <type 'tuple'> (1, 2, "abc")
   ```
2. Unpack a list in the function call and receive the elements as single arguments.

   ```py
   def func2(arg1, arg2, arg3):
       print(type(arg1), arg1, type(arg2), arg2, type(arg3), arg3)

   func2(*[1, 2, "abc"])  # the * unpacks the list to single positional arguments

   # output: <type 'int'> 1 <type 'int'> 2 <type 'str'> abc
   ```